# Work and energy example

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, biophysics

The normal definition of Work, as far as I have read, is: Energy is transferred through work. But I just heard an educationist state this example, where there is a weightlifter who keeps up a huge mass above his head (stationary), and he (the educationist) says that there is no work done, as the force exerted on the mass does not move the mass. But isn't the weightlifter doing work to keep the mass above his head? Or should I assume that there is no work done if a force exerted on an object does not move the object?

Please explain.......

Comment: Hi Ramana. This has been asked before. See the link I've posted above.

Answer (score 0):

When the weightlifter lifts the mass he does work and transfers some energy to the mass which is stored* in the mass as potential energy. Once the bob has been lifted the weightlifter applies a force to keep the bob lifted (to counter the force exerted by the mass downwards i.e. mg) but does no work as the force does not cause any displacement.
Edit: *No object stores potential energy; potential energy is the property of the system and not of a single object.

Comment: No object __stores__ potential energy; potential energy is the property of the system and not of a single object.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 my bad, made the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

There are  two kinds of energy to keep track of: potential energy and kinetic energy. Work can be thought of as the  change in energy (because of the "work-energy theorem"). And the key  question to ask while the weightlifter keeps his weight in the air is: is there a change in energy? 
Kinetic energy is a function  of movement. If there's  no change  in movement, there's  no change in kinetic  energy. Since the weight remains  stationary, the  kinetic  energy remains at where it was (zero kinetic energy since there's  no movement  at all). There is no change in Kinetic energy.
 Potential  energy is a function  of position. Potential  energy can only  change if the object's position  changes. But the  weight remains in the  same position  of space, thereby the potential  energy remains the same. 
There is no change in energy to be found, which  means no work was done.